# How to find the mouse position in Unity using the New Input System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I find the mouse position in Unity? I am using the new Input System and I've already tried

```
InputDevice mouse = Mouse.current;

Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(mouse.position);
```

, but it didn't work. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());
```

Comment: Thanks, but now my ```Physics.Raycast``` doesn't have a reference to my raycast:
```if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            navMeshAgent.SetDestination(hit.point);
        }
```

Comment: @galdeeb-dev I think what the answer wanted to say is: in your code simply replace `mouse.position` with `mouse.position.ReadValue()` ?

Comment: yes, edited the answer as @derHugo suggested.

Comment: Mouse does not exist

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;


float mouseX = Mouse.current.position.x.ReadValue();
float mouseY = Mouse.current.position.y.ReadValue();
Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0));
```